# Executing MPI commands using PHP

Tags: php, mpich

I am trying to execute a mpi program using php as I have to provide a web-interface to user.PHP successfully executes the command and return output only If I have only one process, i.e

```
$output = system(" mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 1 /data/./hello",$returnValue);
```

But I have need more then one process and I have tried following ways but results are same i.e No response from the mpi program.

[image: Always loading, but no response]
**using system ()**

```
$output = system(" mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 2 /data/./hello",$returnValue);
```

**using shell_exec ()**

```
$output = shell_exec(" mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 2 /data/./hello");
```

If I use these methodes to run a simple c program I do receive response.

```
$output = system("/data./hello",$returnValue);
```

Please assist me. Many thanks.

Comment: according to the [documentation for `exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), you need to have safe_mode disabled in order to run any executables outside of safe_mode_exec_dir. Maybe `mpiexec` is outside of safe_mode_exec_dir?

Comment: The same applies to `system()`. However, `shell_exec()` itself is disabled when safe_mode is on. Check if you have [`safe_mode`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Problem seem to be that you are trying to store the output of "system()" into "$output" while it's already storing the value on "$returnValue". Try this:

```
exec('mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 2 /data/./hello', $var);
var_dump($var);
```

For some odd reason PHP doesn't get along with multi threads.

A dirty workarround will be to output the result to a file and feed php from that filem, something like:

```
system(" mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 2 /data/./hello > myfile.txt 2>&1");
$handle = file_get_contents('myfile.txt');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, This above command you provide does not write into file anything, even if I use single thread.

Comment: The first attempt was only redirecting `stdout`, I editted the answer and added redirection of `stderr` also :)

Comment: I have exactly as you have told me but its not working.

Comment: Is `myfile.txt` empty?

Comment: Are you running this on Windows or Linux?
That command should redirect all output to myfile.txt unless output is beign created by a seccond process... You can try to execute `mpiexec -hostfile /data/hosts -np 2 /data/./hello > myfile.txt 2>&1` on  a terminal and see if it outputs anything...

Comment: Hi, thanks I have changed the language, as you mentioned that PHP have some issues with multi-threads.